# Windows 2008 + IIS + Backup folder permissions or script to view all folders with X permissions?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-7.5, file-permissions

I know how to backup IIS 7 configuration, but unaware of a way to backup which folder requires write permissions.

If a server was to go down and I needed to restore, I could restore the config and files easily, but the folders would be lacking permissions that were set for user uploading etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What backup software are you using? Most will preserve file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Server Backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754572(WS.10).aspx) saves the NTFS permissions for all files and folders by default, just like almost every other backup tool for Windows.

If you're unsure, I suggest doing a test-run by restoring your data to a new location, then take a look at the permissions on the restored files.

On the off chance that your backup tool doesn't save the permissions, you might be interested in this technet article about [How to back up and restore NTFS permissions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/11/24/how-to-back-up-and-restore-ntfs-and-share-permissions.aspx). With `icacls` you can save the permissions into a text file and later restore permissions from that same text file.